not getting the message "dependencies added successfully"
I've successfully connected to Firebase, but when I click on "Add Firebase Authentication to your app" and click on accept changes, nothing is happening.
I am not getting any errors as well as I am not getting the message "dependencies added successfully".
enter image description here
i did everything man, but haven't got success yet , please help me with this .!

Are the dependencies added correctly to the build.gradle files?

yes , i did all steps correctly even though i delete android studio entirely but still getting same thing .!
